# Calculate average transcript length of random RNA sequences that have a fixed gc content

Tags: python, random, dna-sequence

trying to calculate average transcript length of random RNA sequences that have a fixed gc content ( 10%, 20%, 30%, …, 90%)

```
def bias_rna(gc_content):
    rna = 'AUG'
    stop_codon = ['UAG','UAA','UGA']
    while rna[-3:] not in stop_codon:
        for _ in range(3):
            rna += random.choice(('A'+'U')*(100-(gc_content))+('C'+'G')*(gc_content))
    return rna


for numb in [range(10,91,10)]:
    rna2_list = []
    for _ in range(1001):
        rna2_list.append(bias_rna(numb))
    rna2_len = []
    for s in rna2_list:
        rna2_len.append(len(s))
    print ('Average random rna length with  cg: %.2f' % (sum(rna_len)/(len(rna_len))))
```

however, the program doesn't work.. suggestions?

Comment: Since this seems to be an issue of specific typos/simple coding errors rather than conceptual issues, it probably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few small modifications and, though I don't know a thing about DNA, it seems to work:

```
import random

def bias_rna(gc_content):
    rna = 'AUG'
    stop_codon = ['UAG','UAA','UGA']
    while rna[-3:] not in stop_codon:
        for _ in range(3):
            rna += random.choice(('A'+'U')*(100-(gc_content))+('C'+'G')*(gc_content))
    return rna


for numb in range(10,91,10):
    rna2_list = []
    for _ in range(1001):
        rna2_list.append(bias_rna(numb))
    rna2_len = []
    for s in rna2_list:
        rna2_len.append(len(s))
    print ('Average random rna length with  cg: %.2f' % (sum(rna2_len)/(len(rna2_len))))
```

Basically, you needed to

- import `random`
- remove the brackets around `range(10,91,10)` (which was causing you to loop through a list containing a single `range` object, rather than the contents of the range itself)
- rename the variable `rna_len` on the last line to `rna2_len`,

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/Nqb3).